# How to calculate Total Execution time for Airflow DAG

Tags: airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

My DAG runs once daily. I want to compute the total execution time DAG took to execute. Is it possible to find this information in Logs or Metadata?

Answer (score 0):

The total execution time can be found in the tree view. There you will get the start time and end time of the job, the difference is the total execution time.  [image: Tree view of dag]

Answer (score 0):

In Airflow (I am working on version 1.10.15) in Task Duration tab there's a checkbox for Cumulative Duration.